# Can I implement Google's AdWord server-to-server "installs" conversion tracking from an iOS app?

Tags: ios, google-ads-api, conversion-tracking

Google's AdWords product supports a [server-to-server API](https://developers.google.com/app-conversion-tracking/api/legacy/ios-conversion-tracking-server).

Give the instructions on that page can I make a call to `https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/MY_CONVERSION_ID/` from within an iOS app or does my App need to call my server enabling my server to make the call?

If I can do from an iOS app are there ObjC or Swift examples?